# How to compile file in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, compilation

I've created file "hello.clj"

```
(ns clojure.examples.hello
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [greetee]
  (println (str "Hello " greetee "!")))
```

and try to compile

```
clojurec hello.clj
```

But I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate hello/clj__init.class or hello/clj.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:367)
    at clojure.core$load__5058$fn__5061.invoke(core.clj:3734)
    at clojure.core$load__5058.doInvoke(core.clj:3733)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:413)
    at clojure.core$load_one__5010.invoke(core.clj:3578)
    at clojure.core$compile__5065$fn__5067.invoke(core.clj:3744)
    at clojure.core$compile__5065.invoke(core.clj:3743)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:346)
    at clojure.lang.Compile.main(Compile.java:56)
```

I try also to put this in the file and run clojore hello.clj

```
(compile 'clojure.examples.hello)
```

But got the same error.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's `clojurec`...? Where did you get it from? I really recommend Leiningen, though (see my answer for details). It's used very widely in the Clojure community and you should have no problem obtaining support in using it.

Comment: It's standard clojure compilator on linux system, its shell script with invoke: exec java -cp /usr/share/java/clojure.jar:"$dest_dir$extra_clas
spath" -Dclojure.compile.path="$dest_dir" clojure.lang.Compile 
"$@"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A namespace called `clojure.examples.hello` needs to reside in a file called `hello.clj` in a directory `$CPDIR/clojure/examples`, where `$CPDIR` is a directory included in the JVM's classpath.

In general, trying to set the classpath and issue the compilation command by hand makes little sense. Use [Leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) instead; the README has a pretty thorough explanation of what you'll need to do.