# Compile clojure source into class (AOT) from command line (not using lein)

Tags: java, clojure

I'm trying to compile clojure source into class file, and run it using command line only, no lein, nor (possibly) reply.

I have core.clj in `src/hello` directory.

```
.
└── src
    └── hello
        └── core.clj
```

This is source code.

```
(ns hello.core)
(defn -main
  "This should be pretty simple."
  []
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

#### using `(compile)` in REPL.

From the hint in this site (http://clojure.org/compilation), I tried to get class file from REPL.

I started REPL with `lein repl` in src directory, then tried to compile to get an error.

```
user=> (compile 'hello.core)

CompilerException java.io.IOException: No such file or directory, compiling:(hello/core.clj:1:1)
```

#### Command line

From this post [simple tool for compiling Clojure .clj into .class / .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926707/simple-tool-for-compiling-clojure-clj-into-class-jar) and [How to compile file in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369898/how-to-compile-file-in-clojure), it seems like that I can compile the clojure source outside REPL.

I tried this in `.` to get an error.

```
> java -cp .:<PATH>/clojure-1.6.0.jar -Dclojure.compile.path=build clojure.lang.Compile src/hello/core.clj 
Compiling src/hello/core.clj to build
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate 
hello/core/clj__init.class or hello/core/clj.clj on classpath: 
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411) 
...
```

So, here are my questions:

- How can I compile the clojure source to get the class with/without REPL?
- How to run the class with Java? Is it enough to execute `java -cp .:CLOJURE_JAR main`?

Comment: and where does gradle join the party?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### REPL

When invoking REPL, you should add class path.

```
java -cp .:<PATH>/clojure-1.6.0.jar:./src clojure.main
```

You need to set the `*compile-path*` with `(set! *compile-path* "build")`.

Then you can compile to get the class file.

```
user=> (compile 'hello.core)
hello.core
```

#### Command line

There are two issues:

1. For compilation, the CP should include the source directory.
2. The parameter is not the file path, but the namespace.

This is to invoke the compiler.

```
clojure> java -cp .:<PATH>/clojure-1.6.0.jar:./src -Dclojure.compile.path=build clojure.lang.Compile hello.core
Compiling hello.core to build
```

#### Execution of the class file

You should point to the directory where the class files are located.

```
clojure> java -cp .:<PATH>/clojure-1.6.0.jar:./build hello.core
Hello, World!
```

#### References

- [Compiling Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123662/compiling-clojure)
- http://clojure.org/compilation